# connecting to aws DynamoDB from docker container running .net application

Tags: .net, docker, amazon-dynamodb

My developer is developing a .net application which is running on docker. It is using the tables in the dynamodb in aws. I am new to DynamoDB and unsure how to connect to it. Is there any endpoint for DynamoDB? He  configured the 
aws credentials in the app.json file, its content is pasted below

```
  "AWS": {
"Profile": "testservice",
"Region": "xxxxxxxx",
"AccessKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"SecretKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 },
"DynamoDb": {
"LocalMode": false
 },
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
   "System": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Information"
  }
},
"AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

but it is not connecting to dynamodb. do we need to set any variable while building the docker?  How to connect to dynamodb tables from the docker container?

Comment: What error message or response do you receive when you try and connect?

Comment: You dont need endpoint. Endpoint only needed when you want to connect from local DB. just specify region and table name. I did work with .NET, i checked some documentation that uses app.conf in XML formate. you dealing with json. and also check Acceskey and secret key have authorized to access Dyanmo DB

Comment: The access key and secret key have the authorize to dynamodb. Not sure why it is not connecting.  I was able to connect by manually injecting the aws key and id when running the docker  `docker run -dit -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="xxxxxxxxxx"  -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --name dockername -p port:port IMAGE ID`